# htaccess - how to separate my own URN address from redirect

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a question about redirecting in htaccess

In my file htaccess I've a rule redirecting all addresses which aren't `dobry-portal.pl` to a `www.dobry-portal.pl` address.

BUT

I want to separate my host adres (URN address) from that redirection. How simply block my own address from redicert. I haven't a static IP. I have to do this because i won't to show my interference in Google Analytics.

Could you help me

Comment: my url adres is www.dobry-portal.pl but my host adres is asurmacz.home.pl. When i do anything on web i do this on address asurmacz.home.pl which is invisible for Google Analytics (track code is assigned to www.dobry-portal.pl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^asurmacz\.
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^.*/([^/,]*,.*) /$1 [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.dobry-portal\.pl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.dobry-portal.pl%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: I have very similar rules:
`
RewriteRule ^.*/([^/,]*,.*) $1 [L,R=301]
rewritecond %{http_host} !^www.dobry-portal.pl [NC]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.dobry-portal.pl/$1 [R=301,L]`

I want to separate my adres asurmacz.home.pl from redirect. Now when i write an address asurmacz.home.pl, redirect rule work and open site on www.dobry-portal.pl, i don't want to redirect this address asurmacz.home.pl

Comment: Something is wrong. When i write asurmacz.home.pl - redirect not work - OK, but when i trying enter on the web on some link - displays 404 Not Found

Comment: What URL do you see browser when you get 404? Answer solves the problem asked that is not redirecting when host name in request starts with `asurmacz`.

Comment: generaly yes, but i have another 3 rules which in this situation not work

RewriteRule ^(.*),(.*),([a-z0-9-_.]+),([a-z0-9-_.]+),([a-z0-9-_.]+)$ $4.php?n=$1&nazwa=$2&t=$3&v=$5 [L,NC,NS,NE]
RewriteRule ^(.*),(.*),([a-z0-9-_.]+),([a-z0-9-_.]+)$ $4.php?n=$1&nazwa=$2&t=$3 [L,NC,NS,NE]
RewriteRule ^(.*),(.*),(.*)$ $3.php?id=$2&n=$1 [L,NC,NS,NE]

could you help me to sort out this all rules to work fine?

Comment: example:
1. I enter on page asurmacz.home.pl - redirect not work - OK
2. I enter on asurmacz.home.pl/Tranformers,main,film,0 - then displays 404 Not Found - this link must works on rules which i've paste in previous comment - actually don't work.

Comment: OK. I've messed up. Sorry. Thanks for help, not works as it should but, i've learned more about htaccess and i'll must learn more. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your host is something like `dobryhost.pl`, add this before the other `RewriteCond` statements (so you may have several `RewriteCond` lines, then `RewriteRule` lines:

```
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_HOST}  !asurmacz [NC]
```

Comment: no. this is not working 
in htaccess i have rules like this

RewriteRule ^.*/([^/,]*,.*) $1 [L,R=301]

rewritecond %{http_host} !^www.dobry-portal.pl [NC]

rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.dobry-portal.pl/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Yes, because it's not the right host in the condition. I just saw your comment above and changed the rule with the right name. Can you try it now?

Comment: is the line RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST}  !asurmacz [NC] will not interfere with the line rewritecond %{http_host} !^www.dobry-portal.pl [NC] ?
I've tried that line and no result

Comment: ` rewritecond %{http_host} !^www.dobry-portal.pl [NC]` is something you added yesterday, right? What I meant in the comment above was that it is not the correct name, and to use `RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_HOST}  !asurmacz [NC]` instead. But it sounds like it is not working.